# R: Multinomial Logistic Regression with a subset of observations (Panel Data)

Tags: r, regression

I have panel data with observations in different week-days to run a Multinomial Logistic Regression in R.

I know that `mlogit` package, include this topic on its usage definition:

`mlogit(formula, data,`**`subset`**`, weights,....)`

But I don't have any example that includes correlations between week-days.

Is it possible? Do you have any example?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly but I'll give it a go. I think you must make sure that your data (subset or not) are structured in the right way. you need to observe each unit in each discrete choice (also in choices not taken). could be that taking a subset messes that up. in my experience with the mlogit package, that's the tricky bit. found the `vignette('mlogit')` quite helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have not only each possible choice in a file, but also a temporal indicator (if the choice was on monday or tuesday, for example). But the problem is that I don't know how to define de 'subset' argument inside the mlogit usage. Do you have an example?

Comment: a reproducible example on your behalf would really be helpful. can you post some code that replicates the structure of your dataset?

Comment: in `help(mlogit)` it says that `subset` is "a vector specifying a subset of obs". probably an index vector? if you can't find a way I guess it's legitimate to write to the `maintainer('mlogit')` of the package and ask for help.

Comment: ok.. my dataset are (by columns): id, choice, cost, time, etc.. but also these temporal dummy variables: id.monday, id.tuesday, id, wednesday, etc..